# TableRow inside TableLayout cause segmentation fault?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, tablerow, android-tablelayout

I'm writing an android application using sdk 2.3.3.

I try using a TableLayout layout xml file with a TableRow inside it.

this is the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:stretchColumns="*"
 android:weightSum="4" >

<TableRow android:id="@+id/table_row_1">

</TableRow>
```

in my GameActivity onCreate() function i have the following code:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);
```

till now I used a different xml layout file that contains a datagird that worked fine.
but for some reason when I load this layout file i get a segmentation fault.

```
08-12 15:15:56.027: D/AndroidRuntime(1056): Shutting down VM
08-12 15:15:56.027: W/dalvikvm(1056): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception     (group=0x40015560)
08-12 15:15:56.087: E/AndroidRuntime(1056): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-12 15:15:56.087: E/AndroidRuntime(1056): java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by     zero
08-12 15:15:56.087: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at     android.widget.TableLayout.mutateColumnsWidth(TableLayout.java:579)
08-12 15:15:56.087: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at     android.widget.TableLayout.shrinkAndStretchColumns(TableLayout.java:568)
08-12 15:15:56.087: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at     android.widget.TableLayout.measureVertical(TableLayout.java:466)
08-12 15:15:56.087: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at     android.widget.TableLayout.onMeasure(TableLayout.java:431)
08-12 15:15:56.087: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
08-12 15:15:56.087: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
08-12 15:15:56.087: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
08-12 15:15:56.087: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
08-12 15:15:56.087: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
08-12 15:15:56.087: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
08-12 15:15:56.087: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
08-12 15:15:56.087: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
08-12 15:15:56.087: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
08-12 15:15:56.087: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
08-12 15:15:56.087: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
08-12 15:15:56.087: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
08-12 15:15:56.087: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-12 15:15:56.087: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-12 15:15:56.087: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-12 15:15:56.087: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 15:15:56.087: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-12 15:15:56.087: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-12 15:15:56.087: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-12 15:15:56.087: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

in general I want to have 4 tableRows and in each one to add 4 ImageViews.

what am I doing wrong ?

thanks!

Kfir

Comment: Where do you get segmentation fault? I see "ArithmeticException: divide by     zero". Because there are no view in table row.

Comment: ohhhhhhhh that's why!!! :) please paste it as an answer. i meant i get an Exception not a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting "ArithmeticException: divide by zero" because there are no view in table row. :)